# Regex word matching

Tags: .net, regex

How can I match words but not letters in culture independent manner?

`\w` matches word or numeric, but I want to ignore numbers. So, "111 or this" with `\w\s` won't work.

I want to get only "or this"?  And I guess `{^[A-Za-z]+$}` isn't the solution becuase say German alphabet has some additional letters.

Comment: Should `or this` be treated as one match or two?

Comment: I want to get match for pattern "word1 word2".  Note that "mark1 is 1" should give me 1 match for "mark1 is".  Also, "My birthday is 11/08/2000" should give match at "My birthday" and "birthday is" (date should not match).

Answer (score 5):

This should work for matching words:

```
\b[^\d\s]+\b
```

Breakdown:

```
\b  -  word boundary
[   -  start of character class
^   -  negation within character class
\d  -  numerals
\s  -  whitespace
]   -  end of character class
+   -  repeat previous character one or more times
\b  -  word boundary
```

This will match on anything that is delimited by word boundaries specifically excluding numerals and whitespace (so "words" like "aa?aa!aa" will be matched).

Alternatively, if you want to exclude these as well, you can use:

```
\b[\p{L}\p{M}]+\b
```

Breakdown:

```
\b    -  word boundary
[     -  start of character class
\p{L} -  single code point in the category "letter"
\p{M} -  code point that is a combining mark (such as diacritics)
]     -  end of character class
+     -  repeat previous character one or more times
\b    -  word boundary
```

Comment: Good call.  I've never used word boundaries before.  Now I will. :)

Comment: This will also match "aaa?", "aaa!", "aaa#" and so on as words.

Comment: @mifki - the punctuation will not be matched. You will need to use something other than `\b` to include those.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it will match entire "aa?aa!aa" as single word as @FailedDev also mentioned below.

Comment: Not only will `[^\d\s]` match punctuation characters, it will match them from the entire Unicode repertoire.  It will also match control characters, box-drawing characters, dingbats, and any other character that doesn't happen to be a digit or whitespace (including letters, of course).  I don't think that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Yes, agreed. This is why I have added more information and another regex that may be closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: This however will not match "String 10/11/2001".  And what about words like "word1", "12inches".

Comment: @Nickolodeon - Seeing as you didn't really give enough examples of what _does_ need to match, what are you expecting?

Comment: Your answer is usefull.  It is that I just noticed in sample input texts that strings with numbers (and dates for that matter) can appear too.  So I update it for us to work further on this problem).

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression `\b[\p{L}\p{M}]+\b`.
It uses not so well known notation to match unicode characters (code points) of specified category. So `\p{L}` will match all letters and `\p{M}` will match all combining marks. Latter is required because sometimes accented characters may be encoded with two code points (letter itself + combining mark) and `\p{L}` alone will match only one of them in such case.

Also please note that this is general expression for matching words that may include international characters. For example, if you need to match several words at once or allow words ending by a digit then this pattern must be modified accordingly.

Comment: Okay, but why?  You should always try to explain why your solution works when the OP's doesn't.  Drive-by answers like this one are discouraged here at SO.

Comment: @AlanMoore I explained it in my comment to FailedDev's answer. I will update my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this :

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"\b[\p{L}\p{M}]+\b");
```

Which will only match all unicode **letters**.

While @Oded's answer may also work, it matches this too : `p+ü+üü++üüü++ü` which is not exactly a word.

**Explanation:**

```
"
\b              # Assert position at a word boundary
[\p{L}\p{M}]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                   # A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language)
                   # A character with the Unicode property “mark” (a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.))
   +               # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b              # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Comment: You need to include `\p{M}` too because accents may be encoded as separate code points.

Answer (score -1):

I think the regex would be [^\d\s]+.  i.e. Not a digit or a space character.